# First section header in .ini file is duplicated by Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup, ini

I can't figure out why the line below creates a *second* duplicate section `frmR` in an `.ini` file that already contains a section with that name.

```pascal
SetIniString('frmR', 'update', 'true', 'C:\junk\test.ini');
```

Contents of `test.ini` file *after* installer is run:

[image]

We thought this might be an encoding issue (we're using version 5.6.1 (u)). But the section names in a hex viewer are also identical:

Contents of `test.ini` file in hex:

[image]

A before and after version of the `test.ini` file is here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1vamZxgTvYpAQcOwOnrTpGG63_Bg7i0Js

Below is the barebones `.iss` file that demonstrates this problem. Put `test.ini` (from the above Google Drive link) in a folder named `C:\junk` before running.

```pascal
[Code]

procedure DeinitializeSetup();
begin
  SetIniString('frmR', 'update', 'true', 'C:\junk\test.ini'); 
end;
```

I discovered that this problem only occurs if the section is the *first* section in the file.  In other words, the file below works fine (without any duplicate section being added):

```
[Test section]
Test=test
[frmR]
Top=28
Left=0
```

The above discovery doesn't resolve the problem, since I have no easy way of assuring that the section I'm writing to is not the first section in the file.

Comment: Did you test without the BOM?

Comment: @SertacAkyuz No I did not test without the BOM.  These ini files (with the BOM) are created by Inno,  so I didn't think that testing a BOM-less file would provide any additional information.

Comment: It may not. It was just an idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Sertac already commented, it is the BOM, for sure. I do not think that Inno Setup creates INI files with BOM. The BOM is just before the first section name. INI file reading/writing functions consider the first line of your file invalid - does not identify it as a section start. Remove the BOM.